# How can I easily merge the tabs of two Chrome windows?

Tags: google-chrome

I have two Chrome windows open with a bunch of tabs. I want to merge the tabs/windows so that all the tabs are in one window. Is there a way to merge them without manually moving each tab from one window onto the other?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about a browser’s functionality.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application as it's defined in [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to superuser.com

Comment: Question already exists on SuperUser - I see no benefit in migrating this https://superuser.com/questions/161893/merging-windows-of-google-chrome

Comment: Ah good find. Thanks all! Agree it’s not in scope

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Click on a tab on one side, hold shift and click the tab on the other side. You now have all of them selected and can simply drag the tabs onto the tab bar of the other window.

This also allows you to close multiple tabs at once or move some tabs to a new window, when they are all selected.

Comment: Ha that was brilliant, I had no idea that was posssible.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but here is one extension for merging all windows into 1 window:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-windows/mmpokgfcmbkfdeibafoafkiijdbfblfg?hl=en

There are probably other extensions too. But I do not endorse any extension since I have not tried it and don't know if it contains spyware (which is a risk that you always take with browser extensions).

When installing the extension, it asks for 1 permission: "It can: Read your browsing history". At least it doesn't ask for "Read contents of the active webpage" so at least it cannot spy on secure text you've typed on pages. But it can read your browsing history (all visited URLs).

However, reading history seems like something that every tab-related extension asks for, and is probably just a side-effect of requesting the API for "managing windows". So it does NOT indicate that the extension IS spying. Just that it CAN do it. I cannot confirm whether it's a clean extension or not.

It currently has 30k active users, and 5 star score with 119 reviews. Take that as you will.

---

Edit: The extension above was the top search result for "merge windows" in Chrome store, but there were a ton more extensions. I skipped anything used by less than 1000 people. That meant that there was only one alternative extension that fit that criteria:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jointabs/bjmimocndihpmdoelbiilpkkfkppikap?hl=en

However, I do not trust JoinTabs or MergeWindows. Both lack Open Source pages where people collaborate on the source. So for me, it's not worth the risks to have a 3rd party extension possibly spy on all your browsing history (whose URLs can contain secure login tokens etc).

Therefore, I am going to do what the accepted answer says: Just shift click on the first and last tabs to select all then manually drag them all into the target window to merge them. I won't use any extensions for it.

---

Also note: It's unrelated to "window merging", but this other extension was found during the same search and I began using it. It's incredible: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb?hl=en It lets you perform fuzzy searching for tabs based on title and domain, and also lets you search bookmarks and browsing history. It is fully open source and has an active github community. Great extension, which helps a lot with tab management!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I cannot drag when all the tabs are selected. What worked for me was:

1. Click the leftmost tab of the windows you want to merge (windowB)
2. Hold shift, and then click the right most tab of the windows you want to merge (windowB)
3. Right click the right most tab (of WindowB), and select "Move tabs to another windows", then select your WindowA

Edit: alright nvm, what you do is:

1. Click the leftmost tab of the windows you want to merge (windowB)
2. Hold shift, and then click the right most tab of the windows you want to merge (windowB)
3. RELEASE SHIFT KEY, then click any of the highlighted tabs (in WindowB), and then you drag them to your WindowA